# Directshow Capture (h264 encode) and Preview

Tags: c#, directshow, video-encoding, directshow.net

I'm trying to develop a C# application for record and preview real time videos from a directshow device source (USB3HDCAP) with max resolution: 1920x1080.

Video must be encoded to H264.

I already tried to use C# computer vision frameworks like Aforge and Accord.FFMPEG. However it doesn't work because encoding is too slow, and then preview gets really delayed.

Than, I tried to make a simple directshow graph with graph edit, using FFMPEG tryout encoder or vfw264, and I get the same result: Preview really slow, and image quality not so good.

For the last I tried [Leadtools Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbJEN.png). The result was perfect, no delay, and record quality pretty good. However Leadtools isn't free.

Do you know a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using Intel Media SDK you can made H264 encoder DirectShow filter, in C++.

Also you can check openH264 project.

x264 is free and produce good quality, but GPL or commercial license.

Answer (score 0):

I am using LAVFilters for a long time and have no problem with it

https://github.com/Nevcairiel/LAVFilters/releases

Comment: Record and Preview ?!

Comment: LVFilters is ffmpeg based DirectShow Splitter and Decoders

Comment: Are you saying that I can preview in real time and record at the same time ?!